# The Legend of Korra Spoiler | Why did Tarrlok try to take over Republica?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

Tarrlok revealed that he was Amon's brother and that he suffered from his bloodbending training with his father in his childhood. He says he hated any minute of it and even disobeyed his father when he was tasked to bloodbend his brother. He also says he could not take it anymore to torture innocent animals.

So why did he go after the dream of his father? Was this even an "avenge me" situation or did he do that for his own goals

Answer (score 2):

From the LoK Wiki page for Tarrlok, We can see in the personality section how they explain this.

> Due to the fostered belief that his father's failure was caused by his obsession with ruling the criminal underbelly, the councilman was obsessed with ruling from the top of power. **His obsession to become the city's "savior" led him to commit immoral, if not illegal, actions,** such as arresting innocent people under false accusations and kidnapping Avatar Korra.

Source: [LoK Wiki](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Tarrlok)

Comment: So he is doing thinks differently that his father because he thought his approatch to gain power was better and so im guessing because "being the savior" of the city is a different goal from that his father had, his actions dont have anything to do with him ? Thats odd. Well I gues he tried to do the opposid of what his father did. Anyway thanks